# Como desenhar Polylines em JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Como faço pra desenhar Polylines em um canvas no JavaFX? estou tentando fazer algo semelhante:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox box = new VBox();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 300, 250);
        scene.setFill(null);

        double x=0.0,y=0.0;
        EventHandler filter = new EventHandler<InputEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(InputEvent event) {
                     Line line = new Line();
        line.setStartX(0.0f);
        line.setStartY(0.0f);
        line.setEndX(100.0f);
        line.setEndY(100.0f);
        box.getChildren().add(line);


            }
        };
// Register the same filter for two different nodes
        scene.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, filter);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
```

Mas acusa erro que dentro de eventos não posso usar scene nem root nem nenhuma dessas variáveis que eu daria a saida da polyline. Alguém consegue me ajudar... ou postar um código usando essas estruturas de dados que eu usei(pra não ficar tão confuso).... obrigado :D

Comment: Não dá pra entender nem a dúvida, compilei e rodou sem nenhum erro.